# Getting rid of negative zero value for float

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, ieee-754

With SQL Server 2008R2 I get a sign difference when rounding the "same" number as decimal or float.

Sample code showing the difference:

```
    DECLARE @f float = -0.00001;
    DECLARE @d decimal = -0.00001;
    PRINT CONVERT(varchar,ROUND(@f, 4))  --- outputs -0
    PRINT CONVERT(varchar,ROUND(@d, 4))  --- outputs 0
```

I need to round the float value to 0, not -0.

I think it boils down to IEEE 754 spec which defines two zero representation (positive and negative) whereas decimals have only one zero. I think the equality operator on floats handles this, but I have to compare two float AS strings for compatibility reasons.

Is there a function/option to get rid of negative zeros (at least when converting to string) ?

Comment: An ugly but effective solution will be this:  

`CONVERT(varchar,CASE WHEN ROUND(@f, 4) = -0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(@f, 4) END)`

Comment: `PRINT  abs(CONVERT(varchar,ROUND(@f, 4)))`

Comment: @RahulTripathi - That will also convert `-4` to `+4`

Comment: @MartinSmith:- Yes, I was specific about 0.

Comment: @RahulTripathi - Nothing in the code you posted is specific about 0.

Comment: On 2012+ you could use `Format(ROUND(@f, 4), '0.####;-0.####;0', 'en-US');`

Comment: @Pascal Try to use abs function.See if it helps you

Comment: What happens if you add 0.0 to it?  If you've got IEEE math, you should get (positive) 0.

Answer (score 3):

Adding 0.0 to the value fixes the issue. Thanks tmyblebu for the answer.

```
     PRINT CONVERT(varchar,ROUND(@f + 0.0, 4))
```

Answer (score -1):

@Pascal Try below code .. Let me know if it has helped you .

```
DECLARE @f float = -0.00001;
    DECLARE @d decimal = -0.00001;
    PRINT abs(ROUND(@f, 4))  --- outputs 0
    PRINT abs(ROUND(@f, 4))   --- outputs 0
```

Comment: This code will output the same value for -4.0 and 4.0. I want to get rid only of negative zero.